# AP with multiple SSIDs and VLANs

Tags: vlan, wifi, 3com

I have some Cisco access points that I have configured with multiple SSIDs. Each SSID has its own VLAN. VLAN 1 for internal networking and VLAN 2 for external users and guests.

Our juniper firewall is configured to accept connections from VLAN 2 and distributes separate DHCP addresses so devices on VLAN 2 only have internet access. The firewall is confirmed to be working in this setup.

The 3com switches that everything is connected to can be configured with access ports, trunk ports or hybrid ports. 
Each AP is connected to one network port so there will be both VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 traffic leaving from this port.

Could anyone give me some help on how to configure the ports on our switches so that clients on the APs get access to the correct vlan?

VLAN 1 is already working so that isn't an issue, what I can't figure out is how to configure some ports so that both VLAN 1 and VLAN 2 will pass over them.

Secondly I have one switch (3com superstack 4200) that can't seem to handle VLANs. If there is an AP connected to it will the tagged vlan packets for vlan 2 pass through it and reach one of our VLAN capable switches?

Comment: What model of Cisco access point are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want hybrid ports set as untagged members of vlan 1 and tagged members of vlan 2. Which vlan actually needs tagged/untagged membership will depend on other configuration elements, but vlan 1 is almost always untagged.